# Kafka logfile location

Tags: kafka

Just to make some things clear: I'm talking about the process logfile that contains the stdout and stderr messages.

This is my systemd unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Kafka server
Documentation=http://kafka.apache.org
Requires=network.target remote-fs.target
After=network.target remote-fs.target

[Service]
Type=simple
PIDFile=/var/run/kafka.pid
User=kafka
Group=kafka
Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre"
Environment="KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/var/log/kafka"

ExecStart=/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /opt/kafka/config/server.properties
ExecStop=/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-server-stop.sh
Restart=on-failure
SyslogIdentifier=kafka

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note that I added the KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS environment variable.

However, that doesn't seem to do anything. This is the output, when I try to start my service:

```
Feb 11 00:55:30 kafka01 kafka[4047]: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/kafka/bin/../logs’: Permission denied
Feb 11 00:55:30 kafka01 kafka[4047]: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Cannot open file /opt/kafka/bin/../logs/kafkaServer-gc.log due to No such file or directory
Feb 11 00:55:30 kafka01 kafka[4047]: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (kafka.Kafka$).
Feb 11 00:55:30 kafka01 kafka[4047]: log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

So, can please someone tell me the correct way to change the location of the kafka log file? KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS doesn't work, KAFKA_LOG_DIR doesn't work either (=I was hoping kafka implemented this similar to zookeeper). The kafka documentation doesn't tell me either.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Question? What is Kafka version did you install? Kafka 2.11-08.2.2 had this bug and it was fixed in late kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1 version. I had this problem before, but since I reinstalled the kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1 it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 7):

For other unfortunate lads like my, you need to modify `LOG_DIR` environment variable (tested for Kafka `v0.11`).

If you open script `kafka-server-start` or `/usr/bin/zookeeper-server-start`, you will see at the bottom that it calls `kafka-run-class` script. And you will see there that it uses `LOG_DIR` as the folder for the logs of the service (not to be confused with kafka topics data).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not actually the answer to the questions but I've arrived here searching for where kafka stores application logs, not producers/consumers data. IMO calling this data logs is really bad naming.

I've deployed a Kafka cluster on GCP Kubernetes engine and I wanted to view the logs of the application and here is how I did it.

1- Get the pods

```
    > kubectl get pods
    NAME      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
    kafka-0   1/1     Running   0          32m
    kafka-1   1/1     Running   0          32m
    kafka-2   1/1     Running   0          32m
    zk-0      1/1     Running   0          23h
    zk-1      1/1     Running   0          23h
    zk-2      1/1     Running   0          23h
```

2- Connect to one of the Kafkas pods with interactive command

```
> kubectl exec -it kafka-0 /bin/bash
```

3- Echo $, in command line type `echo $` and press the tab button several times ... 
you will get a list of all defined environment variables, search for `$KAFKA_HOME` 
or just type

```
> cd $KAFKA_HOME
```

You will get to:

```
/opt/kafka$ ls -al 
total 68
drwxr-xr-x 1 kafka kafka  4096 Aug  2 09:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root  root   4096 Jun 26  2017 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka 28824 Apr 21  2017 LICENSE
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka   336 Apr 21  2017 NOTICE
drwxr-xr-x 1 kafka kafka  4096 Jun 26  2017 bin
drwxr-xr-x 1 kafka kafka  4096 Jun 26  2017 config
drwxr-xr-x 1 kafka kafka  4096 Jun 26  2017 libs
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka  4096 Aug  2 09:37 logs
drwxr-xr-x 1 kafka kafka  4096 Jun 26  2017 site-docs
```

The log directory is what I was looking for ...

Comment: I want to know important Kafka log file names which are useful to confirm whether kafa is working properly or not! Furthermore, any document or link to study logs and troubleshooting kafa will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

As eddyP23 mentioned in previous response... kata-run-class uses LOG_DIR

However there is logic in it to use Script directly parent folder if LOG_DIR variable is not set.

So if your scripts are in kafka/bin folders where you are starting kafka... then logs will be present in kafka/log